# Include external yaml file in ansible task

Tags: ansible

I am creating an ecs_taskdefinition in ansible, but I would like the task-defintion in a sperate file. Can I somehow do something like this:

```
ecs_taskdefintion:
  containers: {{ load_external_yaml containers.yaml }}
  volumes: {{ load_external_yaml_volumes.yaml }}
```

So I want to load the yaml data from external files.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may try to combine [file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html#intro-to-lookups-getting-file-contents) lookup and [from_yaml](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) filter like this:

```
{{ lookup('file','containers.yaml') | from_yaml }}
```

Remember that lookups are local, so containers.yaml should be on ansible control host.

Comment: If you're using vault passwords in the loaded yaml file (i.e. `!vault ...`), this will not work because `from_yaml` will complain that it doesn't have the constructor for it.

Answer (score 4):

Since your file is YAML, you may use `include_vars`
from https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html :

```
- name: Setup vars
  tags: ["always"]
  include_vars:
    file: "./vars/tintin.yaml"
    name: tintin
```

Use `tintin` as a normal var everywhere!